# Android Retrofit update HTTP client configuration

Tags: android, retrofit, certificate-pinning

We have a case where we may have to update the public keys when using Certificate Pinning with OKHttp client and Retrofit. My question is how I would update the certificate pinner of the http client after retrofit has been initialized (like, when a new public key has been received)?

Do I update the CertificatePinner in the http client and then create a new instance of retrofit? Or is there an easier way?

Any suggestions appreciated.

```
OkHttpClient.Builder clientBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
clientBuilder.certificatePinner(NetworkUtils.getCertificatePinner()) ;
OKHTTPClient client = clientBuilder.build();
Retrofit myRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .build();
// Now I need to update the certificate pinner, like this?
client.certificatePinner(NetworkUtils.getCertificatePinner());
myRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .client(client)
                .build();
```

Comment: I think you should create Singleton class for build retrofit object. After getting certificatePinner you can call Singleton call method and change a retrofit object.

Comment: Use an interceptor. When server throws some specific error message, you make a new request to get certificate details, you save them and continue old request with new certificate details.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an interceptor. Something on the lines of inner class ExpiredSessionInterceptor : Interceptor {

```
  override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
        val request = chain.request()
        val response = chain.proceed(request)
        if (response.code() == 202) {
            val newRequest = request.newBuilder().build()
            return chain.proceed(newRequest)
        } else {
            return response;
        }
    }

}
```